# Possible to communication between two host in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am new in block chian development. Now i need to know any ways are available for communicate with multiple host.
That is

I host peer1 in pc1

I host peer2 in pc2

Any ways are available for communicate the both peer.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Composer: 0.16.6
Fabric :1.0.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker Swarm to configure a blockchain network in a multiple host network. Please refer to the below post.

https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f